# Inserting row values into a table which are the column values of another table

Tags: sql-server

What if the opposite of this is to be done.. that is, the column values of one table are to be inserted as the row value of another table. For example suppose that I have a table having data:

Table1

```
a1
b1
c3
d4
```

and I want to insert these columns as a row into another table, supposedly Table2 as:

Table2

```
a1  b1  c3  d4
```

How can this be done using a T-SQL Query..?!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

By using `PIVOT`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: +1 But maybe you should give him example. Sometimes these one in the msdn might seem very difficult especially if he is beginner and we are talking about PIVOT/UNPIVOT functionality.

Comment: I need a simple pivot without making use of any function. I just need to transpose the columns without having to have included any function within the pivot code.